# Adding bootstrap tooltip modifies the style of the element itself - how do I stop this happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/10m0yyuz/24/)

I'm trying to add tooltips to an existing page. We already use bootstrap 2.3 so it seemed like the obvious choice.

My html looks like this, say:

```
<script>
//initialize tooltips
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.my_button').tooltip();   
});
```

```
<div class="my_button_row">
<a href="www.google.com" data-placement='bottom' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some helpful text here!" class="my_button my_button_green">buttonnnnn</a>    
</div>
```

and my CSS looks like:

```
.my_button_row{
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
width: 500px;
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px 5px;    
}

.my_button {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3FACF5, rgba(56, 101, 131, 0.76)) repeat scroll 0% 0% #3498DB;  border-radius: 34px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #666;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 26px;
padding: 10px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: table-cell;
margin: 10px;
white-space: normal !important;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100px;
max-width: 180px;
min-width: 15%;
line-height:26px
}


.my_button_green{
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #63F53F, rgba(79, 131, 56, 0.76)) repeat scroll 0% 0% #61DB34
}
```

When I mouseover the button, the tooltip displayed just as I wanted first time, but the styling on the button itself also appears to change - as you can see from the jsfiddle - how can I stop this from happening?

Edit: I really would prefer a solution that doesn't involve totally changing the way the page is laid out (i.e. 'just remove 'display:block from the container element' is a *much* less straightforward solution than this simplified JSfiddle would make it appear ) - a solution that doesn't modifying the HTML would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `display: table;` from `.my_button_row{` ... or add

`data-container="body"` to

```
<a href="www.google.com" data-placement='bottom' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some helpful text here!" class="my_button my_button_green">buttonnnnn</a>
```

Comment: I can't, the elements in my)button_row need to be styled as a table to display correctly.

Comment: I've just edited my answer, check it that is useful for you.

Comment: (for clarification, the data-container="body" is exactly what I was looking for)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give    `width: 500px;` to `my_button` class and remove

```
  //  max-width: 180px;
 //   min-width: 15%;
```

**[Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10m0yyuz/27/)**

**EDIT:**

According to your requirement from the comments:

Adjusted the padding instead of giving width statically

**[Updated Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/10m0yyuz/28)**

Comment: giving the buttons static width would mean redesigning the entire page for the sake of adding tooltips.... surely this isn't the best way?

Comment: You gave 500px to the outer div of that button which was static too, I just gave the same static width to the button

Comment: Btw it depends where your button is positioned in the document,If you are into responsive design may be giving static width is a bad idea else this would do

Comment: it's a simplified example to illustrate the problem - the actual buttons are part of a much more complicated page and can't have a static width :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to `.my_button`.

You'll have to fiddle around with the margins and padding to get the text in the center of the button, but this will fix your issue.  Also keep in mind that with `display: block`, the button will be at most 180px wide due to your`max-width` style.

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because you have used `display:table-cell` css property for the button while the tooltip is being appended as `display:block` element.

Simply use `display:block` for `.my_button`(or remove the `display:table` property from `.my_button_row`) and you are good to go

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10m0yyuz/25/)

Comment: There's no way to change how the tooltip works instead? comments indicate that display:table-cell was the only way to get the page to look to spec.